# How to ensure Traceur output is compatible with amd/commonjs

Tags: amd, commonjs, ecmascript-harmony, webpack, traceur

I want to run my ES6 though **Traceur**. However I would also like to use Webpack which can accept AMD modules or commonjs.

I was wondering if traceur gone through any steps to be compatible (ES5 output maintains **requires+defines** etc) with these and whether I can go ahead with my Webpack builds not worrying about Traceur.

Answer (score 1):

The established module systems, i.e. AMD & CommonJS all still work. Traceur does some pretty straightforward source translation – akin to CoffeeScript – and old-style module definitions are not affected.

ES6 modules and imports/exports are not yet properly implemented in Traceur, so you won't be able to use those yet.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully will be able to use ES6 directly with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

import/export is fully implemented, but there is still work to be done on the loader. You can use CommonJS or AMD